# Git merge library from another project

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

We counter following problem we tried to solve for many hours

Let's have 2 projects in git... they are different repositories. 
One is library and second is some new project that will use mentioned library.

**Library project contains:**

- directory /lib
- directory /plugins

**New project contains:**

- directory /www
- directory /lib
- directory /plugins
- directory /assets
- etc... whatever

What we want to achieve is "merge" library into our New project

We tried using submodules, subtrees but what it creates inside our new project is new git folder without merge...

Thank you

Comment: Make a clone of your "new project" repository. Add your library repository as a remote, fetch from this remote, merge allowing unrelated histories. Will this work?

Comment: Do you really want to intertwine the history of your library with the history of this new project? You can't safely push back to the original library repository without the whole "new project" tagging along. Are you sure submodules aren't what you want?

Comment: I think submodule is what we want, we want do be able to develope library and new project as two different parts. when library is updated, we want to merge(update changes)... @LasseV.Karlsen as remote, we it will be treated as one project right? Thanks

Comment: Correct, after fetching, your library history will be part of the new project history. This is all well and good for the version of the library for the new project, but you cannot then sit in the new project repository, fix some things in the library, and then push those things back into the library project. If you do, this will bring along all unrelated changes in the new project as well. So yes, submodule seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: And no, you will not be "merging" your library into the new project repository then. It's best if you go read up on how submodules work, and create a small set of test repositories that you can experiment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both your library project and new project have the folders `lib` and `plugin`, so you can pull changes from library project to new project. Then the files in `lib` folder and `plugins` folder of library project will add to `lib` folder and `plugins` folder of new project separately.

Steps as below:

```
# In new project repo
git remote add lib <URL for library project git repo> -f
git pull lib master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**Note:** If there has conflicts when you pull changes from library project, you can modify and save the conflict files, and then use `git add .` and `git commit`.

Answer (score 0):

- it's unclear whether or not the two libraries are in the same git repository or not?
- can you share how is the repository structured ? where do each of these libs is held ?
- is it a different location or is it simply importing this lib from a different branch.
- if it's a different branch you simply git cherry-pick the commit which added the lib.
- if it's a different location - use git-mv 
  anyway, it's one or the other or a combination of the two.

gl.